# JavaScript offline routing library for OpenStreep Maps

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

Is there any library written in JavaScript for offline routing, to generate routes based on OSM data?
And is there any with leaflet support?

Comment: Probably not, and it sounds horribly slow. Better take a look at real online and offline [routing solutions for OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not generally advised (see scai's comment above), you actually *can* do offline routing in JavaScript, for example by using [graphhopper cross-compiled to js](https://karussell.wordpress.com/2014/05/04/graphhopper-in-the-browser-teavm-makes-offline-routing-via-openstreetmap-possible-in-javascript/) or [any of these libs](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=javascript+dijkstra&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults).

Comment: Absolutely perfect answer.
And I now installed graphhopper standalone on a custom server and use it online as was advised.