# Offline maps and routing on hybrid app

Tags: routes, gis, openstreetmap, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm developing app for smartphones that requires offline map and routing. App is going to be hybrid. I chose Ionic but i have no problem switching to another platform.

At first i thought that i could do it with freeware tools. Generate my own tiles in back-end server, get the tiles to smartphone and draw them with leaflet. But rolling my own offline routing seems like a really bad idea. I'd rather use some commercial solution, that i can plug in to my app.

What would be a good solution to use in my hybrid app? I don't care if its paid for or free. Can offline routing be done on smartphone at all? I'm pretty new to GIS, can someone nudge me to the right direction?

Edit: my maximum route length from one point to another is about 3 km

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

A quick search for "javascript map offline routing" should give you some hints.

E.g. [JavaScript offline routing library for OpenStreep Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102211/javascript-offline-routing-library-for-openstreep-maps)

---

If you need offline routing, you will need the raw (vector) OpenStreetMap data, not pre-rendered (raster) tiles.

Otherwise, how your routing algorithm will know roads?

You might be interested in [OsmAnd app](http://osmand.net/), it is open source (GPLv3).
I do not think it is hybrid, though.

Comment: But that is a stand alone app.

Comment: Yes, but since it is open source, you can tear it apart. But as said in the above answer, the biggest concern would probably be the language.

Comment: I came to conclusion that the best thing would be to build my own cordova plugin that does routing on native side and uses already existing library like graphhopper. Routing and java are both unknown to me. Well... better get to work then.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution, although it requires substantial amount of work as you say… Good luck and be proud to share your plugin! :-)